# Google Maps Marker drag event

Tags: google-maps

Please help me with the code I found in this site. I could not make it to work.
   Thank you.

```
Here is the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/VDjAw/3/

The event does not trigger.
```

Comment: Please post the code you have a question on, not just a link or a fiddle.

Comment: Sorry. I'll keep that in mind next time. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y68AH/1/)

1. You need to add Google Maps API to `External Resources`
2. You need to set width and height for `#map_canvas`, otherwise you will see nothing even if code is OK
3. You need to fire `initMap()` to start working :)

Comment: thanks man. I figured that the eventlisteners should be inside the initMap function. it is working now.